# bind keypress in jquery with no plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need a simple bind on a keypress (right arrow) but i just cant make it work
i dont know on what should i chain the .keypress() method and the variable just wont take the key code in. it reacts on key press (it logs it on the console) but just not what i want. i am not alowed to use any plugins or jquery UI.

```
    $("*").keypress(function(e){
        console.log(e); //this returns [object object]
        if (e.which == 39 || e.keyCode == 39 || window.event.keyCode == 39){
            $('.someDiv').click();
        };
    });
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document` object, also note that jQuery normalizes the `which` property and it is cross-browser:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(event){
    if (event.which == 39){
        $('.someDiv').click();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`keypress` does not seem to fire on arrow keys, so how about something like this instead :

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which == 39){
        $('.someDiv').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Also, jQuery normalizes `e.which`, and binding to the document seems like a better idea rather then iterating over every element in the DOM.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPY6s/)